# Response.write() not returning value

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I've been following [this tutorial](http://danielnill.com/nodejs-tutorial-with-socketio/) for an introduction on nodejs, but I'm having trouble returning something with response.write().

My server.js code works fine in returning "hello world" when I go to domain:8001, but navigating to domain:8001/socket.html returns a blank screen.

I've used console.log to check that the code to write "socket is here." is being executed, but I'm not sure why it isn't doing anything.

server.js:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    console.log('Connection');
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
            console.log(__dirname);
            console.log(path);

    switch(path){
        case '/':
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.write('hello world');
            break;
        case '/socket.html':
            fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data){
                if (error){
                    response.writeHead(404);
                    response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
                }
                else{
                    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});

                    response.write("socket is here.");
                }
            });
            break;
        default:
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
            break;
    }

    response.end();
});

server.listen(8001);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

socket.html: (though it shouldn't matter what is contained in it)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
    <script>
      var socket = io.connect();
    </script>
    <div>This is our socket.html file</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried with a page that doesn't try to load a script? The browser stops parsing the page while the script is loading, and if there is a problem there that might explain the blank page.

Comment: I tried socket.html without scripts, but it seems to give me the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ending the response before waiting for `fs.readFile()` to complete. Try this:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    console.log('Connection');
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
            console.log(__dirname);
            console.log(path);

    switch(path){
        case '/':
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.write('hello world');
            break;
        case '/socket.html':
            fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data){
                if (error){
                    response.writeHead(404);
                    response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
                }
                else{
                    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});

                    response.write("socket is here.");
                }
                response.end();
            });
            return;
        default:
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
            break;
    }

    response.end();
});

server.listen(8001);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Also, doing `fs.readFile(__dirname + path, ...);` is potentially dangerous because someone could send a request like `/../../../../../../etc/passwd`. What you should do there instead is use the `path` module to resolve/normalize `__dirname + path` to an absolute path, and then ensure that that absolute path starts with the absolute path of your public directory.